# Como excluir item de um ComboBox após selecioná-lo?

Tags: javafx

Utilizo um `ComboBox` para adicionar um objeto em uma `TableView` e queria que logo após o usuário clicar no objeto desejado, este item fosse adicionado na `TableView` e saísse da lista do `ComboBox`.

Tentei assim mas dá `NullPointerException`:

```java
public void handleAddTeacherEvaluator(){

    Teacher t = addTeachersBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    auxTeachers.add(t); //adicionando na ObservableList da tableView
    addTeachersBox.getItems().remove(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adaptar solução a seguir ao seu contexto: (Como não tenho como simular seu contexto testei apenas com remoção de índice)

```
combobox.setOnHidden((event) -> {
        int index = combobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if(index > 0){ // Evita erros quando não há seleção
            combobox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(); 
            combobox.getItems().remove(index);
        }
    });
```

Quando um item é selecionado o comportamento normal do combobox é fechar o menu, logo coloquei algo para ser executado toda vez que o contextMenu fechar e houver algo selecionado (index > 0). É importante que esse if exista para evitar erros no remove. Espero que ajude!